# FMS Live video stream suffer if chat uses same NetConnection?

Tags: actionscript, video-streaming, flash-media-server

Have a Flex/FMS web meeting app that has multiple custom components - live streaming camera, chat, slide dec.

Each component does its share of communicating through the FMS server.  Should all three of those things share one NetConnection object in the application or will the live video stream suffer when users chat or the meeting presenter advances slides and such?

Answer (score 0):

I think they will suffer but I think you need to build logic to make it as pleasant as possible. E.g. always make sure that the audio steam has the highest priority. There is nothing worse than listening to audio that keeps dropping out. Then give priority to the video. I'm not sure what FMS you're using but you could use a bandwidth meter to detect the current band width and reduce the quality of the video based on that. I think that most people rather see the quality of the video drop than really slow updated frames. I think the slides are the least of your worry. Just make sure than the next slide is loading in the background while you're watching the current one so you don't have to wait long when moving to the next slide.